# How can i access the current url in a sharepoint custom webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I have created a custom webpart and deployed it in sharepoint. Now i want to modify the webpart and use the **url** of the site page where the web part is embedded. How can i access the url progmatically?

Comment: In the webpart codebehind?

Comment: yes, in the C# code! @KyleMuir

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean in the Webpart codebehind you can reference it like this:

```
string currentWebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
```

NOTE: SPContext.Current.Site\Web (unlike new SPWeb\SPSite) does NOT need to be disposed.

Hope this helps.

Resource:

- SPContext MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms475883.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! i got what i want :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will give you access to the url and then you can do whatever your trying to do:

```
 using (var spSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
 using (var spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
 {          
  // code here
 }
```

Comment: SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb (what you just did in those 2 using statements) would be much more efficient, also that way you wouldn't have to wrap it in using statements.

Comment: It kinda depends what he is looking for, if he wants to create his own new instance or use a existing object, but yeah your right :)

Comment: @Rohander thanks for response. however i accepted the answer of Kyle as that was the first answer and that solved my problem. Couldn't give an upvote to your answer because of low reputation.